# How to disable the Editable ALV Grid in case of an incorrect entry?

Tags: abap, alv

Whenever an invalid value is entered in an ALV Grid, how do I disable the other fields (grey out) in the grid and force the user to fix the incorrect field.

I have tried adding protocol in DATA_CHANGED event. But protocol list only shows the error in popup. Editing is still possible and no fields are disabled.

But how do I disable the other fields. Sample behavior as shown below:

[image]

Here, the other fields are greyed out and the invalid entry is highlighted. Until the user fixes this error, he/she cannot proceed further.

Comment: SAP GUI has async architect, you can not get changes sync to server. All data post to server with user button attraction (save, refresh, etc). There is way to get changes from client with given delay in second. So you can get changes for every second and make changes on grid. I know there will be lag or performance issue.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot get the changes until user triggers an event. I recall reading somewhere that OO ALV variant has `data_changed` (or something like that) event, which you can use to validate your changes. You can google "Disable alv cell" to find some examples (also oo alv) of disabling cells. I assume you can figure out the rest. I am not sure if there's a better way to do this, but the method I suggested (cell-by-cell) seems to be really inefficient  (lots of processing if you have a big table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having screen 100 with container CCONTAINER1 paste this snippet

```
CLASS zcl_alv_test DEFINITION.

  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS: constructor, display_grid, populate_grid.

    DATA: lr_rtti_struc   TYPE REF TO cl_abap_structdescr,
          it_fldcat       TYPE lvc_t_fcat,
          grid_container1 TYPE REF TO cl_gui_custom_container,
          grid1           TYPE REF TO cl_gui_alv_grid.

    DATA: BEGIN OF gs_outtab.
            INCLUDE TYPE spfli.
    DATA: celltab TYPE lvc_t_styl.
    DATA: END OF gs_outtab.
    DATA gt_outtab1 LIKE TABLE OF gs_outtab INITIAL SIZE 0.

    METHODS:
      handle_data_changed FOR EVENT data_changed OF cl_gui_alv_grid IMPORTING er_data_changed,
      handle_data_changed_finished FOR EVENT data_changed_finished OF cl_gui_alv_grid IMPORTING e_modified et_good_cells,
      create_dynamic_fcat.

  PRIVATE SECTION.
    TYPES: ty_tab LIKE LINE OF gt_outtab1.
    METHODS: refresh_grid, fill_celltab IMPORTING p_fieldname TYPE lvc_fname
                                        CHANGING  pt_celltab  TYPE lvc_t_styl.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS zcl_alv_test IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD constructor.
    CREATE OBJECT grid_container1 EXPORTING container_name = 'CCONTAINER1'.
    CREATE OBJECT grid1 EXPORTING i_parent = grid_container1.

    SET HANDLER handle_data_changed FOR grid1.
    SET HANDLER handle_data_changed_finished FOR grid1.

    CALL METHOD grid1->register_edit_event
      EXPORTING
        i_event_id = cl_gui_alv_grid=>mc_evt_enter.
  ENDMETHOD. "constructor

  METHOD fill_celltab.
    LOOP AT pt_celltab ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_fcat>).
      IF <fs_fcat>-fieldname = p_fieldname.
        <fs_fcat>-style = cl_gui_alv_grid=>mc_style_enabled.
      ENDIF.
    ENDLOOP.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD handle_data_changed.
    DATA: lt_celltab TYPE lvc_t_styl.

    LOOP AT it_fldcat ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_fcat>).
      INSERT VALUE lvc_s_styl( style = cl_gui_alv_grid=>mc_style_disabled fieldname = <fs_fcat>-fieldname ) INTO TABLE lt_celltab.
    ENDLOOP.
    MODIFY gt_outtab1 FROM VALUE ty_tab( celltab = lt_celltab ) TRANSPORTING celltab WHERE connid IS NOT INITIAL.

    LOOP AT er_data_changed->mt_mod_cells ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<mods>).
      READ TABLE gt_outtab1 ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<sym>) INDEX <mods>-row_id.
      fill_celltab( EXPORTING p_fieldname = <mods>-fieldname
                                CHANGING pt_celltab = <sym>-celltab ).
      MODIFY gt_outtab1 FROM <sym> INDEX <mods>-row_id.
    ENDLOOP.
    refresh_grid( ).
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD handle_data_changed_finished.
    DATA: lt_celltab TYPE lvc_t_styl.

    LOOP AT it_fldcat ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_fcat>).
      IF sy-tabix MOD 2 = 0.
        DATA(style) = cl_gui_alv_grid=>mc_style_disabled.
      ELSE.
        style = cl_gui_alv_grid=>mc_style_enabled.
      ENDIF.
      INSERT VALUE lvc_s_styl( style = style fieldname = <fs_fcat>-fieldname ) INTO TABLE lt_celltab.
    ENDLOOP.

    MODIFY gt_outtab1 FROM VALUE ty_tab( celltab = lt_celltab ) TRANSPORTING celltab WHERE connid IS NOT INITIAL.
    refresh_grid( ).
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD create_dynamic_fcat.
    lr_rtti_struc ?= cl_abap_structdescr=>describe_by_name( 'SPFLI' ).
    DATA(comps) = lr_rtti_struc->components.

    LOOP AT comps ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<comps>).
      IF sy-tabix MOD 2 = 0.
        DATA(edit) = abap_false.
      ELSE.
        edit = abap_true.
      ENDIF.
      APPEND VALUE lvc_s_fcat( edit = edit fieldname = <comps>-name datatype = <comps>-type_kind inttype = <comps>-type_kind intlen = <comps>-length decimals = <comps>-decimals coltext = <comps>-name lowercase = 'X' ) TO it_fldcat .
    ENDLOOP.
  ENDMETHOD. "create_dynamic_fcat

  METHOD populate_grid.
    SELECT * UP TO 1000 ROWS
    FROM spfli
    INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE gt_outtab1.
  ENDMETHOD. "CHANGE_TITLE

  METHOD display_grid.
    create_dynamic_fcat( ).
    grid1->set_table_for_first_display(
      EXPORTING
        is_layout       = VALUE lvc_s_layo( zebra = abap_true stylefname = 'CELLTAB' )
      CHANGING
        it_outtab       = gt_outtab1
        it_fieldcatalog = it_fldcat ).
  ENDMETHOD. "display_grid

  METHOD refresh_grid.
    cl_gui_cfw=>flush( ).
    grid1->refresh_table_display( ).
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

MODULE status_0100 OUTPUT.
  SET PF-STATUS 'MAIN100'.
  DATA: yalv TYPE REF TO zcl_alv_test.
  CREATE OBJECT yalv.
  yalv->populate_grid( ).
  yalv->display_grid( ).
ENDMODULE.

MODULE user_command_0100 INPUT.
  CASE sy-ucomm.
    WHEN 'BACK' OR 'EXIT' OR 'RETURN'.
      LEAVE PROGRAM.
    WHEN OTHERS.
  ENDCASE.
ENDMODULE.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  CALL SCREEN 100.
```

It uses the concept of [cell styles](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_erp60_sp/6.0/en-US/88/387f380c2f2e3ce10000009b38f8cf/content.htm?no_cache=true), where each row in table is assigned a table of styles for each of the column in this row. There you can apply conditional attributes on a cell level, including editability.

When throwing an error through builtin checktables/domains, the grid is made not editable except erroneous cell, and when correcting the error, editability returns.